# Formated output in java like ls

Tags: java, formatting, output

I have list of names of files and directories in directory for example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<Strings>(); /* list of files */
```

and I need to print it like command ls in linux do that.

```
a.txt file1.txt       filewithverylongname.txt Folder1
g.txt G_longfile2.txt h.txt                    i.txt
```

Number of columns depends on number of files and size of columns depends on length of each file or directory name in same column. 
If I know number of files I would use something in in [this link](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)
but the number of files or directories could be variable ..
How can I do it?

Comment: Ok now. What have you tried fit that solution in your case?

Comment: I tried it with static length of columns and static numbers of columns. But I have no idea how to do it dynamic like ls do that.

Comment: I wouldn't normally think of output formatting as a part of the file-system, but then again, I haven't seen the wording of your task so what do I know... Anyway, for this kind of optimiztion I would think you need some application of dynamic programming (but I haven't done any of it since I was in school, so I can't help with the details...) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Answer (score 0):

To get number of files in folder

```
File file = new File("D:\\AnyFolder");
if(file.isDirectory()) {
   File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
   System.out.println("Total files in folder : " + listFiles.length );
}
```

Comment: We are implementing our own file system in java as school work .. I actualy have names of files in ArrayList of Strings like I mentioned, I can get number of files or lengths of each name but main problem is with dynamic output formating.

Answer (score 0):

Before printing anything, you'll need `A`greatest filename length; and `B`output medium's line length; so you can calculate the number of columns that fit the output medium: `C=B/(A+1)` (stick to integers and everything's gonna be allright). Now, given the `N`Number of filenames, you may derive how many rows you need: `R=(N/C)+1` and you may loop on this

```
for (int i = 0; i < R; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < C; ++j)
        if (C*i+j < N)
            System.out.print(list[C*i+j]) + ' ';
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would satisfy your requirement:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Ls {

    private static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 3;
    private static final int SEPARATING_SPACE_LENGTH = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:/WINDOWS");
        if(file.isDirectory()) {
           File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
           list(listFiles);
        }
    }

    private static void list(File[] files) {
        int[] maxLength = new int[NUM_COLUMNS];

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            int fileLength  = files[i].getName().length();
            int columnIndex = i % NUM_COLUMNS; 

            if (maxLength[columnIndex] < fileLength) {
                maxLength[columnIndex] = fileLength;
            }   
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            String fileName = files[i].getName();
            System.out.print(fileName);
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength[i % NUM_COLUMNS] - fileName.length() + SEPARATING_SPACE_LENGTH; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

            if ((i + 1) % NUM_COLUMNS == 0) {
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Let me know if it's not clear.

Thanks,
EG